# How to get a regular expression to match all occurrences instead of just one?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all values in a string that are separated by a '.' character.

Some examples are

aaa.bbb

fdsg.dfgfd

HH.dd

An example string would look like aaa.bbb dfd gf HH.dd

No numbers. Just a string of lower and/or upper case letters separated by a period and then another string of lower and/or upper case letters.

I have come up with the following regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+
```

This works somewhat, but it only matches the first occurrence in the input string. All the others are being ignored.

I have also tried wrapping it the expression in parenthesis as well as adding another + after that parenthesis, yet it continues to match the first occurrence and ignore the rest.

```
([a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+)+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In which programming language do you use this pattern? Can you show the code pls.? (Looks good to me, so maybe you're doing something wrong in the way you work with it...)

Comment: Hey guys, I am trying it over at https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Dave you missed to add a `g` modifier beside the input box of pattern.. see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jM6gJ5/1)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Karthik! Glad to know I missed a config step instead of messing up the regex.

Comment: Thank you to everyone else who responded as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex would be

```
/[a-z]+.[a-z]+/gi
```

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

[image: Trying out in regex101.com]